# How create SESSION with dynamically name?

Tags: php, variables, session, store

The Example code:
I have variable `$getname` that get informations from the url **`GET`**

```
$getname=$_GET['id'];
```

If it possible to store session like this, cause it doesn't work for me.

```
$_SESSION[$getname]=$_GET['id'];
```

Because i need to create for every id individually session with the same values.

PROBLEM SOLVED:
$getname='name'_$_GET['id']; //cause $_GET['id'] was a number, that couldn't be the session name.

$_SESSION[$getname]=$getname;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way..

```
$getname=$_GET['id'];
$_SESSION[$getname]=$getname;
```

So you can access like

```
echo $_SESSION[$getname]; //Prints what you really had in the $_GET['id'] variable from the URL
```

### A simple example..

```
<?php
session_start();
$getname="hello";
$_SESSION[$getname]=$getname;
echo $_SESSION[$getname];
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
hello
```

Comment: But is one problem i've met. That's working for example if $getname='asdas'; //if string is here
But if under the $_GET['name'] will be numbers it doesn't work.

Comment: That is because variable names never start with `numbers`

Comment: I got it. What i need is to use casting operator like (string).
Cause i fall out of my mind. SESSION can't store numbers as name.

Comment: perfect. the best solution i saw

Answer (score 1):

The `$_SESSION` would be the other way round :

```
        $getinput = $_GET['id'];
        $_SESSION['name your session here']=$getinput
```

;

Comment: I know it as well as i am.
But i need $_SESSION['name your session here']
'name your session here' was exactly the same as $getinput.

Comment: I've solved this problem, 'cause i try to put numbers as session variable name X_x.
Thanks for helping me.
Example code:
$getinput = $_GET['id'];
$_SESSION[$getinput]='name_'.$getinput;

And it's working well.

Answer (score 0):

Why create an array element that has the exact same key as a value? Just create an array of the IDs that can iterate over later:

`$_SESSION['needed_ids'][] = $_GET['id']`

Add some checks to cleanly create the array first, and filter the incoming data.