# dynamically name session isset how to use?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies, isset

I am trying to get dynamic `$_SESSION[$id]` on the second page shown below, but its not working (as per the printout):

**First page url**

```
https://example.com/test.php?id=1548393
```

**First page code**

```
<?php 
session_start();

$id = $_GET['id'];
$_SESSION[$id] = "mysecretstringline";

?>
```

**Second page url**

```
https://example.com/test2.php?id=1548393
```

**Second page code**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$id = $_GET['id'];

if(isset($_SESSION[$id])){
 echo "working";
}else{
 echo "not working";
}
?>
```

Comment: $_SESSION['id'] is the correct way.

Comment: Do not use variables inside a session variable

Comment: please see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879839/how-create-session-with-dynamically-name

Comment: i am trying to use variables inside a session

Comment: brother you may not call an array element with the variable index. this is basic PHP. $_SESSION is an associative array.

Comment: You can't use a numeric index for $_SESSION, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797251/notice-unknown-skipping-numeric-key-1-in-unknown-on-line-0  (specifically, the first answer)

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? If you do, you should have seen `Notice: Unknown: Skipping numeric key 1548393 in Unknown on line 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found problem we can not use numeric index for $_SESSION

but we can use number in $_SESSION by convert number to roman numerals

first page url

```
https://example.com/test.php?id=1548393
```

first page code

```
<?php 
session_start();

$roman_id = romanic_number($_GET['id']);
$_SESSION[$roman_id] = "mysecretstringline";


        function romanic_number($integer, $upcase = true) 
        { 
            $table = array('M'=>1000, 'CM'=>900, 'D'=>500, 'CD'=>400, 'C'=>100, 'XC'=>90, 'L'=>50, 'XL'=>40, 'X'=>10, 'IX'=>9, 'V'=>5, 'IV'=>4, 'I'=>1); 
            $return = ''; 
            while($integer > 0) 
            { 
                foreach($table as $rom=>$arb) 
                { 
                    if($integer >= $arb) 
                    { 
                        $integer -= $arb; 
                        $return .= $rom; 
                        break; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 

            return $return; 
        } 

?>
```

second page url

```
https://example.com/test2.php?id=1548393
```

second page code

```
<?php 
session_start();

$roman_id = romanic_number($_GET['id']);

if(isset($_SESSION[$roman_id])){
 echo "working";
}else{
 echo "not working";
}


            function romanic_number($integer, $upcase = true) 
            { 
                $table = array('M'=>1000, 'CM'=>900, 'D'=>500, 'CD'=>400, 'C'=>100, 'XC'=>90, 'L'=>50, 'XL'=>40, 'X'=>10, 'IX'=>9, 'V'=>5, 'IV'=>4, 'I'=>1); 
                $return = ''; 
                while($integer > 0) 
                { 
                    foreach($table as $rom=>$arb) 
                    { 
                        if($integer >= $arb) 
                        { 
                            $integer -= $arb; 
                            $return .= $rom; 
                            break; 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 

                return $return; 
            } 

    ?>
```

output

```
working
```

thanks @gre_gor and @Katie

Answer (score 0):

Could be that in your normal code (this just looks like a quick mockup), you have a space after ?> somewhere. That could cause issues.

```
<?php
// start.php
session_start();
$id = $_GET['id'];
$_SESSION[$id] = "mysecretstringline";
```

and

```
<?php
// next.php
session_start();
$id = $_GET['id'];
if (isset($_SESSION[$id])) {
    echo "working";
} else {
    echo "not working";
}
```

works for me. Notice no ?> characters.

**UPDATE**:

The following might be of interest regarding session name constraints ([can a php $_SESSION variable have numeric id thus : $_SESSION['1234’]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450371/can-a-php-session-variable-have-numeric-id-thus-session1234))

You have that issue in your example you could just add an `id_` and then do the same check when validating/getting the session.